# Relative completeness of a relative cocompletion of a subcategory

Tags: ct.category-theory, limits-and-colimits, categorical-logic

I'm going to use the language from Lack and Rosicky's *Notions of Lawvere theory*, but I won't be touching on actual enriched category theory.

Suppose I have a category $\mathbb{C}$ with a class of limits and colimits, $\Phi, \Psi$ respectively, that commute with each other. Now suppose I have a  subcategory $\mathbb{C}'$ that is closed to $\Phi$-limits, are there any conditions under which the $\Psi$-cocompletion of $\mathbb{C}'$ in $\mathbb{C}$ will be $\Phi$-complete?